# Java SSL/TLS Handshake

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, https, openssl

im writing a small HTTP/S Server for an Embeded Device Framework.

Because i use plain Java Sockets i need to implement the TLS/SSL myself.

For the Client Handshake i wrote following Function:

```java
if (secureIO) {
  // Print Message if Client Handshake was correct.
  ((SSLSocket) clientIO)
      .addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandshakeCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent eventIO) {
          logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.SUCCESS,
              "Handshake with Client "
                  + clientIO.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " via Method "
                  + eventIO + " was correct.");

          // Unlock Stream Lock.
          lockIO[0] = false;
        }
      });

  // ((SSLSocket) clientIO).setNeedClientAuth(true);
  // Session Creation Blocks everything...
  ((SSLSocket) clientIO).setEnableSessionCreation(true);

  // Set Cipher and Protocols for Client.
  ((SSLSocket) clientIO)
      .setEnabledProtocols(((SSLServerSocket) tcpIO).getEnabledProtocols());
  ((SSLSocket) clientIO)
      .setEnabledCipherSuites(
          ((SSLServerSocket) tcpIO).getEnabledCipherSuites());

  // Start Handshake to Client.
  ((SSLSocket) clientIO).startHandshake();
}
```

The Problem is, when i opening the Socket Port in the Browser, the Page loads forever.
So i tried to debug the SSLSocket with OPENSSL it seems that the Handshake gets not fully finished.

[image]

I thought some Stream gets confused by an Listener on my Server, but i disabled the Input/Output Stream entirely with the lock bool, until the Handshake Complete Listener gets executed.

Some outstanding Debug Traces from the Server have given me this theory.

```
javax.net.ssl|ALL|1C|Server-Socket|2022-07-08 21:51:57.696 CEST|SSLSessionImpl.java:250|Session initialized:  Session(1657309917387|TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|1C|Server-Socket|2022-07-08 21:51:57.696 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 50
javax.net.ssl|FINE|1C|Server-Socket|2022-07-08 21:51:57.697 CEST|SSLCipher.java:2013|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 04 00 00 2E 00 01 51 80   F9 1F 1E 31 01 01 00 20  ......Q....1... 
  0010: E5 5B CF E4 29 3B 0E 9F   E4 12 D7 CD 8B 34 2C 22  .[..);.......4,"
  0020: 0B 14 45 B3 E9 94 CC 62   64 C3 06 E4 4F 72 82 D3  ..E....bd...Or..
  0030: 00 00 16 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  0040: 00 00 00                                           ...
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|1C|Server-Socket|2022-07-08 21:51:57.697 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 17 03 03 00 53 6B D3 EE   EF C5 DD D2 E3 3F DF 15  ....Sk.......?..
  0010: 13 87 A5 9E BB AC 0A 1F   1F 6A 77 50 B1 4D 51 39  .........jwP.MQ9
  0020: 4D 0C 00 78 D1 4A D8 78   79 9A 79 7E AD EB 20 80  M..x.J.xy.y... .
  0030: 91 C3 A5 14 33 FF 13 01   9B D6 37 7E 3A 7B 9F 7D  ....3.....7.:...
  0040: 03 E6 59 90 FF 9B E3 63   87 18 FD 84 37 C7 21 CA  ..Y....c....7.!.
  0050: A7 AC ED 25 C3 05 73 A8                            ...%..s.
)
```

Heres an example of my Read Function, the InputStream is setet after the `Socket.accpet()` Method:

```java
private void read(InputStream streamIO, java.net.Socket clientIO) {
  // todo: Test Performance between execute and submit.
  poolIO.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // clientIO.isConnected() && !tcpIO.isClosed() &&
        while (!shutdownIO && clientIO.isConnected() && !tcpIO.isClosed()) {
          // Byte Buffer ho contains read Data.
          // @todo: add buffer max size, read until -1 (EOF).
          byte[] bufferIO = new byte[streamIO.available()];

          // Read Data into Buffer and store (EOF).
          int codeIO = streamIO.read(bufferIO);

          if (codeIO != 0 || bufferIO.length != 0) {
            System.out.println(codeIO);
            System.out.println(bufferIO.length);
          }

          // Check if bytes in the Buffer.
          if (bufferIO.length != 0 && streamIO.available() == 0) {
            if (binaryIO)
              binary(new Socket(clientIO), bufferIO);

            if (stringIO)
              string(new Socket(clientIO), new String(bufferIO, charsetIO));
          }

          if (eofIO && (codeIO == -1)) {
            break;
          }

          // Sleep for 100 Milliseconds (CPU Usage)
          Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        streamIO.reset();
        streamIO.close();
        clientIO.close();

        disconnect(new Socket(clientIO));

        // Clear Buffer Stream.
        // bufferIO = new byte[0];
      } catch (IOException | InterruptedException errorIO) {
        if (errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Stream closed.")
            || errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Connection reset")) {
          logIO.debug(GuardianLog.Type.INFO,
              "Client with IP " + clientIO.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
                  + " disconnected from Server with Port " + networkIO.getPort()
                  + ".");

          disconnect(new Socket(clientIO));
        } else if (errorIO.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("sleep interrupted")) {
          logIO.debug(
              GuardianLog.Type.WARNING, "Socket Thread interrupted.", errorIO);
        } else
          logIO.append(
              GuardianLog.Type.ERROR, "Socket throw an Error ", errorIO);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where exactly does it hang? When reading data (when exactly)? When establishing the SSL/TLS connection?

Comment: It returns only a Socket for me, i casting the normal ``ServerSocket to an SSLServerSocket`` and calling the ``accept`` Method.

Comment: and where exactly does it hang?

Comment: It hangs when I establish the SSL/TLS Connection in the OpenSSL log it’s starting the Handshake but then printing the R BLOCK Message and nothing else.

Comment: **That's normal.** OpenSSL was created by geeks and frequently uses jargon, but `read R BLOCK` means "the handshake completed and now we're ready to send and/or receive data". OpenSSL can do _any_ data; a _browser_ requires HTTP-format data, so _after_ the SSL/TLS handshake does your server read an HTTP request and send a properly-formatted (and complete) HTTP response? Alternatively, if your server isn't supposed to implement HTTP, don't try to use a browser.

Comment: PS: a 'child' SSLSocket obtained from SSLServerSocket.accept already has enabledProtocols and enabledCipherSuites set from the parent, so your code that repeats that is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the enormes Tip with ``R BLOCK`` normally the SSLServerSocket has the Same Listeners as the ServerSocket, but eventually is here the error as you said. So when ``R BLOCK`` means the Handshake is finished it must be an HTTP Server error, so i think the SSLServerSocket with HTTP Listeners is not answering correctly.

Comment: I can write messages trough the Output Stream of the Server to the Client but the Input Stream from the Server is all the time empty. Its the same mechanics as my ServerSocket and there the Stream works...

Comment: I think the issue is outside the code that you supplied. Are you sure you are trying to read / write from the `SSLSocket` instance? Do you try to read out the input stream *before* using the output stream? Are you sure you don't close the input stream?

Comment: I using the Output Stream for testing Purposes before the Input Stream reading. But normally the Input Stream gets used first. I completed my Question on the top with the reading function. Im reading from an Socket Object, should i cast it to an SSLSocket? Im sure that i don't close the input stream.